# accessing list items by selenium web driver and storing them to list

Tags: selenium

I want to store element one, element two...as mentioned below in a list by web driver...find the page source code

```html
<div class="widget">
<div class="widget">
 <h2>Programs</h2>
   <div class="w">
    <ul class="xoxo blogroll">
      <li>
        <li><a title="Element ONE" href="http://www.zemtv.com/?s=4+Man+show">Test ONE</a></li>
        <li><a title="Element Two" href="http://www.zemtv.com/?s=8pm+with+Fareeha+Idrees">Test Two</a></li>
        <li><a title="Element three" href="http://www.zemtv.com/?s=Aaj+kamran+khan">Element Three</a></li>
        <li>
        <li>
```

I am using the code like below

```cs
List<WebElement> allNames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xoxo blogroll']/a"));
```

but it is not accessing any list items. Can any body help me in this regard.

Comment: the html code is given in comments

Answer (score 1):

xpath used in the above code is not pointing to anchor tag.

```
//div[@class='xoxo blogroll']/a
```

should be replaced with

```
//ul[@class='xoxo blogroll']/li/a
```

Comment: Or: //div[@class='xoxo blogroll']//a  (double slash)

Answer (score 0):

```
     List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='xoxo blogroll']/a"));
     for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
     {System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText();}
```

Comment: Please provide a brief overview to your answer.

Comment: findElements() is always going to return  List<WebElement> , use java collection concept